# Change textview color which is adapted in a listview from custom layout

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-custom-view

I have a ListView that contains several TextView items which are located in a custom layout . This list is created at runtime, and can vary in size. I used a SimpleAdapter for ListView

I would like to Change TextViews Color based on some conditions.

i tried this but it did not change anything

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Measurements.this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view,null);
    TextView before = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.before_t);
    TextView after = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.after_t);
    TextView fasting = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fasting_t);

    while (data.moveToNext()) {
    if(data.getDouble(2)>110) before.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

here is the listview adapter

```
 SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.custom_row_view,
            new String[]{"line1", "line2", "line3", "line4"},
            new int[]{R.id.date, R.id.before_t, R.id.after_t,R.id.fasting_t});
    listview.setAdapter(sa);
```

Could you point out the solution for this ?

Comment: it should be `R.color.RED` I think so

Comment: You need to change the color in your custom adapter class...which you have not posted with your question.

Comment: It's not custom adapter@Barns

Comment: And why is that? @Barns

Comment: Because you are trying to reference a view this is being displayed in the row of a `ListView` that is being constructed "behind the scenes"  you need to change the properties of certain view while they are being created.

Comment: Read my answer how you can do it while in BTS. @Barns

Comment: @ShashankMishra :: Perhaps your solution will work...good luck to the OP, but I consider this solution quite rigid and limited making future changes difficult.

Comment: Yaa creating a custom adapter will be a more dynamic way, you are right. And one more thing Are You Bucky Barns? @Barns

Comment: LOL no man :) @Barns

Answer (score 0):

Use these line of code:-

1> ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.RED);

or

2>getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white);

This line of code work for me.